# POST request to /api/notes/addnote endpoint returning 404 Not Found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I'm encountering an issue when making a POST request to the **`/api/notes/addnote`** endpoint. The server responds with a 404 Not Found error. I have checked the server-side code and verified that the endpoint is correctly defined. Here are the details of my setup:

Server-side:

Framework/Language: Express.js

Code snippet handling the **`/api/notes/addnote`** endpoint:

```
router.post('/addnote', fetchUser, [
    body('tittle', 'Tittle cannot be blank').exists(),
    body('description', 'Description must be atleast 5 characters').isLength({ min: 5 })
], async (req, res) => {
    // If there are any errors in the validation of an express request, return status 400 and the errors
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    } 

    // Creating a new note in the database and saving it
    const { tittle, description, tag } = req.body;
    const note = await Notes.create({
        tittle,
        description,
        tag,
        user: req.id
    });

    // Sending the note as a response
    res.json(note);
});

module.exports = router;
```

main.js file code:

```
const connectToMongo = require('./Db');
const express = require('express');

connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api/notes/addnote', require('./Routes/notes'));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Client-side:

Code snippet for making the POST request:

[image]

The server is running and accessible at localhost:3000

I have successfully tested other endpoints on the same server, and they are working correctly.

I have confirmed the URL for the POST request: **`http://localhost:3000/api/notes/addnote`**.

I have already attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Double-checked the server-side code and endpoint spelling.
- Tested the POST request using different HTTP clients (e.g., Postman) with the same result.
- Reviewed the server logs for any error messages related to the **`/api/notes/addnote`** endpoint.

Despite these efforts, I'm still receiving a 404 Not Found error. Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The route is `/api/notes/addnote/addnote` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL while setting the `Router` to the appliction is the same as you have mentioned.

```jsx
app.use('/api/notes', require('./Routes/notes'));
```

The problem here is:

```js
app.use('/api/notes/addnote', require('./Routes/notes'));
router.post('/addnote');
```

Now the route works for `/api/notes/addnote/addnote`.

Answer (score 1):

The routes aren't defined right. Change:

```
app.use('/api/notes/addnote', require('./Routes/notes'));
```

To

```
app.use('/api/notes', require('./Routes/notes'));
```